# Cannot connect to USB GSM Modem using Python

Tags: python, usb, serial

I am having trouble connecting to a 3G usb modem using python.

when I try, in python interpreter:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB1", timeout=2)
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 236, in __init__
     self.open()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 286, in open
     self._update_dtr_state()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 612, in _update_dtr_state
     fcntl.ioctl(self.fd, TIOCMBIS, TIOCM_DTR_str)
  IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

but running

```
cu -l /dev/ttyUSB1
```

is able to connect just fine.  And I am able to send AT commands and get responses.

Serial object printed out is:

```
Serial<id=0x76add9b0, open=True>(port='/dev/ttyUSB1', baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=2, xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to disable the flow control.  You can see it failing on a ioctl TIOCM_DTR_str.

```
ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB1", timeout=2, xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False)
```

You may need a timeout 0 too, you'll see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the offending code, I tried setting dsrdtr to True will skip the code that tries to update the DTR line (that causes the broken pipe).

Basically, I just added:

```
ser.dsrdtr = True
```

and it works.  I do not understand why the code will skip setting the DTR line if dsrdtr is True, though.  I expected a False value will skip, not a True value.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.